# Using CSS, setting div class to drop to another line?

Tags: css

Using CSS, can I set a div class to some text on a paragraph to drop it to the line below?

I tried float: left; and it moved the text to the beginning of the paragraph which is a good start as I would want the text on the left, but I need it on the line below.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="tweet">
<ul class="tweet_list">
<li class="tweet_odd">
<span class="tweet_text">This is a tweet</span>
<span class="tweet_time">1 minute ago</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code to show the `div` structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to the div you want to drop below, it may do the trick:

```
 <div style="clear: both;">
```

- Inline css is not optimal way though, this would be better done in a style-sheet.

Comment: @stefgosselin, you are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Using a `<div>` inside of a `<p>` is actually semantically incorrect. You should put an inline element such as a `<span>` element inside of your `<p>` tag, and then make the `<span>` a block-level element.

The structure of your code would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<p>This is some text in your paragraph. 
<span class="newline">This text will appear on a new line.</span> 
This is some more text in a paragraph, which will also appear on a new line.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.newline {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunate timing, as he's just added his HTML, and there's no `<p>` in sight :)

Comment: You posted your code after I had already started working on your answer, but the same concept applies - just make your span `tweet_text` and `tweet_time` block-level elements by applying the CSS `display: block;`